# Applying transformations to data coming from an STL file

Tags: export, graphics3d, import, geometric-transform

I am very new with the use of 3D graphics in *Mathematica*, so my question might be very naive. I need to Import an STL file, apply transformations to it (rotation and translation), and export it back to an STL file.

I have seen the STL-related questions already posted, but they don’t seem to help me.  It’s not just the visualisation of the 3D graphics that I need to rotate, but the entire set of facets, with respect to the origin.

Please let me know if I need to clarify things, or provide more details.

Comment: Very briefly: after importing your *. stl file as `Import[filename, "GraphicsComplex"]`, apply `RotationTransform[]`/`TranslationTransform[]` to the point list in the first argument of `GraphicsComplex[]`, and then export `Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[newpoints, otherstuff]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick answer (based on @J.M.'s comment) for a basic rotation:

```
 STLdata = Import["MyFile.stl", "GraphicsComplex"];

 RotatedSTL = 
   Graphics3D[
     GeometricTransformation[STLdata, RotationTransform[30 Degree, {1, 1, 1}]], Axes -> True]

 Export["MyFileRotated.stl", RotatedSTL, {"STL","BinaryFormat" -> False}]
```

Answer (score 1):

In version 10.2 (perhaps going back to 10.0, but I cannot verify that), by default STL's are imported as `MeshRegion` objects. Assuming that `casefn` is a string representing the path to an STL file, you can see all the elements available for import from the file

```
Import[casefn, "Elements"]
(*{"BinaryFormat", "BoundaryMeshRegion", "Comments", 
"CoordinateTransform", "FacetNormals", "Graphics3D", 
"GraphicsComplex", "MeshRegion", "PolygonCount", "PolygonData", 
"PolygonObjects", "Summary", "VertexData", "VerticalAxis"} )*
```

If you use the default `MeshRegion`, then use `TransformedRegion` with the `*Transform` family of geometric transform functions to transform the region

```
case = Import[casefn, "STL"]; 
center = Mean /@ RegionBounds[case]; 
centered = TransformedRegion[case, TranslationTransform[-center]]
```

of course, you would use `RotationTransform` for your problem, but shearing, scaling, reflection, and other geometric transforms are also available. Personally, I do not like the default appearance of `MeshRegion` objects with edges displayed, so I use a different style

```
MeshRegion[Import[casefn, "STL"], PlotTheme -> "Polygons"]
```